# Is there a way to protect content(images, sounds) in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have some apps in the Apple app store that have lots of expensive images and sounds. There are apps now, like PhoneView and PhoneDisk, that can easily load the contents of apps, and the material can be downloaded.

Is there a method to protect against this?

Comment: DRM has so many interpretations. But the truth is: possibly. I'm less concerned about the app code, than the contents - which do not belong to the developer. What if they appear on the net, and the small business content provider is upset. a. Am I liable? b. I don't want my clients to have their property stolen while I am trusted with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obfuscate your assets. From the simple (removing file extensions) to the difficult (encrypting them), but if someone *really determined* to see your assets, there's no way to stop them.

Comment: I guess I started this thread sort of thinking that. Hopefully, it will make people think about the situations they may find themselves in - especially with regard to assets.